# How to pass data arguments to a named route in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

Hi I'm a newbie in flutter, I have a screen that I'm using `Navigator.push`. i'd like to route from my Button Page to the chat message page.

Please see code below:

Issue: My problem is that I need to pass arguments in the `IndividualPage()` for navigation

```
class ButtonScreen extends StatelessWidget {
   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return Scaffold(
       appBar: AppBar(backgroundColor: Colors.red, title: const Text("Chat Request")),
       body: Center(
         child: ElevatedButton(
           onPressed: () {
             Navigator.push(
                 context,
                 MaterialPageRoute(
                   builder: (context) =>  IndividualPage(),),);
           },
           child: const Text(
             'Request Chat',
           ),
         ),
       ),
     );
   }
 }
```

Please also see my  `IndividualPage Widget`

```
import 'package:chats_s/ownMessageCard.dart';
import 'package:chats_s/replyCard.dart';
import 'package:chats_s/Model/chat_model.dart';
import 'package:chats_s/Model/message_model.dart';
import 'package:emoji_picker/emoji_picker.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/svg.dart';
import 'package:socket_io_client/socket_io_client.dart' as IO;

class IndividualPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const IndividualPage({ Key? key, required this.chatModel, required this.sourchat})
      : super(key: key);
  final ChatModel chatModel;
  final ChatModel sourchat;

  @override
  _IndividualPageState createState() => _IndividualPageState();
}

class _IndividualPageState extends State<IndividualPage> {
  bool show = false;
  FocusNode focusNode = FocusNode();
  bool sendButton = false;
  List<MessageModel> messages = [];
  TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController();
  ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController();
  late IO.Socket socket;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // connect();

    focusNode.addListener(() {
      if (focusNode.hasFocus) {
        setState(() {
          show = false;
        });
      }
    });
    connect();
  }

  void connect() {
    // MessageModel messageModel = MessageModel(sourceId: widget.sourceChat.id.toString(),targetId: );
    socket = IO.io("http://10.0.2.2:5000", <String, dynamic>{
      "transports": ["websocket"],
      "autoConnect": false,
    });
    socket.connect();
    socket.emit("signin", widget.sourchat.id);
    socket.onConnect((data) {
      print("Connected");
      socket.on("message", (msg) {
        print(msg);
        setMessage("destination", msg["message"]);
        _scrollController.animateTo(_scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent,
            duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300), curve: Curves.easeOut);
      });
    });
    print(socket.connected);
  }

  void sendMessage(String message, int sourceId, int targetId) {
    setMessage("source", message);
    socket.emit("message",
        {"message": message, "sourceId": sourceId, "targetId": targetId});
  }

  void setMessage(String type, String message) {
    MessageModel messageModel = MessageModel(
        type: type,
        message: message,
        time: DateTime.now().toString().substring(10, 16));
    print(messages);

    setState(() {
      messages.add(messageModel);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        Image.asset(
          "assets/whatsapp_Back.png",
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
        ),
        Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          appBar: PreferredSize(
            preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(60),
            child: AppBar(
              leadingWidth: 70,
              titleSpacing: 0,
              leading: InkWell(
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                },
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Icon(
                      Icons.arrow_back,
                      size: 24,
                    ),
                    CircleAvatar(
                      child: SvgPicture.asset(
                        widget.chatModel.isGroup
                            ? "assets/groups.svg"
                            : "assets/person.svg",
                        color: Colors.white,
                        height: 36,
                        width: 36,
                      ),
                      radius: 20,
                      backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              title: InkWell(
                onTap: () {},
                child: Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(6),
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        widget.chatModel.name,
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 18.5,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        "last seen today at 12:05",
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 13,
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              actions: [
                IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.videocam), onPressed: () {}),
                IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.call), onPressed: () {}),
                PopupMenuButton<String>(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                  onSelected: (value) {
                    print(value);
                  },
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext contesxt) {
                    return [
                      PopupMenuItem(
                        child: Text("View Contact"),
                        value: "View Contact",
                      ),
                      PopupMenuItem(
                        child: Text("Media, links, and docs"),
                        value: "Media, links, and docs",
                      ),
                      PopupMenuItem(
                        child: Text("Whatsapp Web"),
                        value: "Whatsapp Web",
                      ),
                      PopupMenuItem(
                        child: Text("Search"),
                        value: "Search",
                      ),
                      PopupMenuItem(
                        child: Text("Mute Notification"),
                        value: "Mute Notification",
                      ),
                      PopupMenuItem(
                        child: Text("Wallpaper"),
                        value: "Wallpaper",
                      ),
                    ];
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          body: Container(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            child: WillPopScope(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    // height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 150,
                    child: ListView.builder(
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      controller: _scrollController,
                      itemCount: messages.length + 1,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        if (index == messages.length) {
                          return Container(
                            height: 70,
                          );
                        }
                        if (messages[index].type == "source") {
                          return OwnMessageCard(
                            message: messages[index].message,
                            time: messages[index].time,
                          );
                        } else {
                          return ReplyCard(
                            message: messages[index].message,
                            time: messages[index].time,
                          );
                        }
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                  Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                    child: Container(
                      height: 70,
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                        children: [
                          Row(
                            children: [
                              Container(
                                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 60,
                                child: Card(
                                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                                      left: 2, right: 2, bottom: 8),
                                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
                                  ),
                                  child: TextFormField(
                                    controller: _controller,
                                    focusNode: focusNode,
                                    textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.center,
                                    keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                                    maxLines: 5,
                                    minLines: 1,
                                    onChanged: (value) {
                                      if (value.length > 0) {
                                        setState(() {
                                          sendButton = true;
                                        });
                                      } else {
                                        setState(() {
                                          sendButton = false;
                                        });
                                      }
                                    },
                                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                                      border: InputBorder.none,
                                      hintText: "Type a message",
                                      hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                                      prefixIcon: IconButton(
                                        icon: Icon(
                                          show
                                              ? Icons.keyboard
                                              : Icons.emoji_emotions_outlined,
                                        ),
                                        onPressed: () {
                                          if (!show) {
                                            focusNode.unfocus();
                                            focusNode.canRequestFocus = false;
                                          }
                                          setState(() {
                                            show = !show;
                                          });
                                        },
                                      ),
                                      suffixIcon: Row(
                                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                                        children: [
                                          IconButton(
                                            icon: Icon(Icons.attach_file),
                                            onPressed: () {
                                              showModalBottomSheet(
                                                  backgroundColor:
                                                      Colors.transparent,
                                                  context: context,
                                                  builder: (builder) =>
                                                      bottomSheet());
                                            },
                                          ),
                                          IconButton(
                                            icon: Icon(Icons.camera_alt),
                                            onPressed: () {
                                              // Navigator.push(
                                              //     context,
                                              //     MaterialPageRoute(
                                              //         builder: (builder) =>
                                              //             CameraApp()));
                                            },
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                  bottom: 8,
                                  right: 2,
                                  left: 2,
                                ),
                                child: CircleAvatar(
                                  radius: 25,
                                  backgroundColor: Color(0xFF128C7E),
                                  child: IconButton(
                                    icon: Icon(
                                      sendButton ? Icons.send : Icons.mic,
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                    ),
                                    onPressed: () {
                                      if (sendButton) {
                                        _scrollController.animateTo(
                                            _scrollController
                                                .position.maxScrollExtent,
                                            duration:
                                                Duration(milliseconds: 300),
                                            curve: Curves.easeOut);
                                        sendMessage(
                                            _controller.text,
                                            widget.sourchat.id,
                                            widget.chatModel.id);
                                        _controller.clear();
                                        setState(() {
                                          sendButton = false;
                                        });
                                      }
                                    },
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                          show ? emojiSelect() : Container(),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              onWillPop: () {
                if (show) {
                  setState(() {
                    show = false;
                  });
                } else {
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                }
                return Future.value(false);
              },
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget bottomSheet() {
    return Container(
      height: 278,
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      child: Card(
        margin: const EdgeInsets.all(18.0),
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)),
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 20),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  iconCreation(
                      Icons.insert_drive_file, Colors.indigo, "Document"),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 40,
                  ),
                  iconCreation(Icons.camera_alt, Colors.pink, "Camera"),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 40,
                  ),
                  iconCreation(Icons.insert_photo, Colors.purple, "Gallery"),
                ],
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 30,
              ),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  iconCreation(Icons.headset, Colors.orange, "Audio"),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 40,
                  ),
                  iconCreation(Icons.location_pin, Colors.teal, "Location"),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 40,
                  ),
                  iconCreation(Icons.person, Colors.blue, "Contact"),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget iconCreation(IconData icons, Color color, String text) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: () {},
      child: Column(
        children: [
          CircleAvatar(
            radius: 30,
            backgroundColor: color,
            child: Icon(
              icons,
              // semanticLabel: "Help",
              size: 29,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 5,
          ),
          Text(
            text,
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 12,
              // fontWeight: FontWeight.w100,
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget emojiSelect() {
    return EmojiPicker(
        rows: 4,
        columns: 7,
        onEmojiSelected: (emoji, category) {
          print(emoji);
          setState(() {
            _controller.text = _controller.text + emoji.emoji;
          });
        });
  }
}
```

I tried to remove the `required` but it gives me and error.

Here is my chatModel:

```
  String name;
  String icon;
  bool isGroup;
  String time;
  String currentMessage;
  String status;
  bool select = false;
  int id;
  ChatModel({
    required this.name,
    required this.icon,
    required this.isGroup,
    required this.time,
    required this.currentMessage,
    required this.status,
    this.select = false,
    required this.id,
  });
}
```

Comment: https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/navigation

Comment: please add the whole code for ` individual page`

Comment: Hi @Manishyadav please see code for individual page

Answer (score 2):

Try to implement the following, First of all, you need to specify the parameter and its type name, icon, etc.

```
class newPage extends StatefulWidget {
 final String prevpage;
 const newPage({Key? key,required this.prevpage}) : super(key: key);
 @override
 State<newPage> createState() => _MyAboutPageState(prevpage);
}
```

In your IndividualPage try to do this

```
class _MyAboutPageState extends State<newPage> {
 String requiredTitle;
 _MyAboutPageState(this.requiredTitle);
```

Then when you call the page you need to pass the parameters, here you can send any parameter required by the contractor method,

```
Navigator.push(context,MaterialPageRoute(builder:(context)=> newPage(requiredTitle: "New Home") ));
```

OR

```
routes: <String, WidgetBuilder> {
 '/about': (BuildContext context) => newPage(requiredTitle: "Home page”,),
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm Invinting you to take a loock to the official
[docs here](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/navigation/navigate-with-arguments)

Answer (score 1):

So when you are using your your `instance` than make sure that all the `required fields` are used and passed as an argument while using anywhere in application.